Is it possible to improve metabolic rate through quorum sensing?
I am building a microbial fuel cell unit using mint plant and soil microbes. My goal is to power a LED light using the electricity but the electrify that microbes are so little so I am thinking of methods to fix this with quorum sensing
Currently, I found that riboflavin could potentially enhance the production of biofilm through quorum sensing. Have anyone tried this approach out yet? Or are there other recommend methods that could help this process? Huge thanks in advance!!

Welcome. We ask questions to be accompanied by some background research, this helps to focus the question to something answerable. The current question is too open-ended and we are not a discussion forum. What have you found so far on this topic?
